# Uploading file with Youtube API v3 and PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a file to youtube using the new api v3. Here's what I do...

```
public function upload(){

    if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])) {

        $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();

        $snippet->setTitle("Test v3");
        $snippet->setDescription("First upload using api v3");
        $snippet->setTags(array("api","v3"));

        $video = new Google_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);

            $response = $this->googleapi->youtube->videos->insert(
                "status,snippet",
                $video,
                array('data' => $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])
                );

            var_dump($response);

  }else{
    $this->load->view('youtube');
  }
}
```

The response is empty, because `io/Google_REST.php` throws

> 'Undefined index: errors' at line 70

which is within `decodeHttpResponse()`,

however, a dump from the actual response of `Google_Client::$io->makeRequest()` returns the following...

```
object(Google_HttpRequest)#31 (10) { ["batchHeaders":"Google_HttpRequest":private]=>  
array(4) { ["Content-Type"]=>  string(16) "application/http" ["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]=>
string(6) "binary" ["MIME-Version"]=>  string(3) "1.0" ["Content-Length"]=>  string(0) "" }
["url":protected]=>  string(197) "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube
/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=multipart&
key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
["requestMethod":protected]=>  string(4) "POST" ["requestHeaders":protected]=>  
array(3) { ["content-type"]=>  string(37) "multipart/related; boundary=131050532"
["authorization"]=>  string(64) "BearerXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
["content-length"]=> int(254) } ["postBody":protected]=>  string(254) 
"--131050532 Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 {"snippet":{"tags": 
["api","v3"],"title":"Test v3","description":"First upload using api v3"}} --131050532  
Content-Type: Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 c2FtcGxlLm1wNA== --131050532--"  
["userAgent":protected]=>  string(44) "Youtube test app google-api-php-client/0.6.0"  
["responseHttpCode":protected]=>  int(500) ["responseHeaders":protected]=>  array(7) {  
["server"]=>  string(61) "HTTP Upload Server Built on Dec 12 2012 15:53:08 (1355356388)"  
["content-type"]=>  string(16) "application/json" ["date"]=>  string(29) "Wed, 19 Dec 2012  
13:03:00 GMT" ["pragma"]=>  string(8) "no-cache" ["expires"]=>  string(29) "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 
00:00:00 GMT" ["cache-control"]=>  string(35) "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ["content-
length"]=>  string(2) "52" } ["responseBody":protected]=>  string(52) "{ "error": { "code": 500, 
"message": null } } " ["accessKey"]=>  NULL }
```

Any help moving forwards with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't attempted a PHP upload yet, so this is mainly general advice. First, video.snippet.categoryId is mandatory when performing uploads. Second, if you pass part="snippet,status" to the API, then you need to set both the video.snippet properties (which you are) and video.status properties (which you're not). You can get by with leaving out status and just using part="snippet" if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Read example between "this is the work in action!" and "end Work!":

```
<?php
@session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['google']))
    $_SESSION['google'] = array('state'=> null, 'token'=> null);

#include core google
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/Google');
require_once  'Google/autoload.php';

$redirectUri = 'http://127.0.0.1/myPathWork/index.php';

##set client:
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('myAppName');
$client->setClientId('myClientId');
$client->setClientSecret('myClientSecret');
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
#important! scopes 
$client->setScopes(array(
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 
                )); 

if(isset($_GET['code'])){

    if (strval($_SESSION['google']['state']) !== strval($_GET['state']))
      exit('The session state did not match.');

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['google']['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('location:'. $redirectUri);  
}

if(isset($_SESSION['google']['token']))
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['google']['token']); # este es el key

if ($client->getAccessToken()){
    try {
        #this is the work in action!
        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
        $client->setDefer(true);

        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle('My Video title');
        $snippet->setDescription('My Video Description');
        $snippet->setTags(array('video upload','youtube v3', 'etc..'));
        $snippet->setCategoryId(22); # view: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list

        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->setPrivacyStatus('private'); #private, public, unlisted
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        $client->setDefer(true);
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client,$insertRequest,'video/*', null,true,$chunkSizeBytes);

        #file location:
        $media->setFileSize(filesize('/var/www/my/path/video.mp4'));

        #Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen('/var/www/my/path/video.mp4', 'rb');

        while (!$status && !feof($handle)){
          $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
          $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
          fclose($handle);

           if ($status->status['uploadStatus'] == 'uploaded')
              echo "ok, " . $status['snippet']['title'] . ' - '. $status['id'] . "<hr>";
           else
            echo "error: " . $status['snippet']['title'] . ' - ' . $status['id'] . "<hr>";

            #show more print_r($status['snippet']);
        }

      $client->setDefer(false);
      #end Work!  
    }
    catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
      exit('Error:' . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }
    catch (Google_Exception $e) {
      exit('Error:' . htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage())); 
    }
    $_SESSION['google']['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
else{
     #GET NEW TOKEN
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['google']['state'] = $state;
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();    
    header('location:' . $authUrl);
}
```